# Can ASP.NET CORE MVC be hosted in Xamarin App(Android)?

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, .net-core

I have a **ASP.NET CORE MVC (.NET CORE 3.1)** application running well on [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in Windows, Now I'm wondering if possible to migrate it to Android via Xamarin?

The purpose of this move is the lower cost of Android device.

And I noticed: *[Run ASP.NET Core 3.0 apps with MonoVM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5)*
but seems no details?

Comment: Do you want to implement the functionality of the web application in an Android app, or do you want to have an Android app be the hosting application for the ASP.NET application? Because if the last one is the case: why??

Comment: @rickvdbosch I don't know the difference of your options, could you clarify more? My situation is, before, I had a Windows device that hosting the ASP.NET CORE MVC well, but the device is expensive, so I have to switch to a cheap Android device.

Answer (score 1):

No, Not yet (Jan 2021).

Xamarin, NetFramework, Net5, NetCore3 all support NetStandard. AspNetCore is based on NetCore, not NetStandard. If AspNetCore was a NetStandard library, it would support it, but AspNetCore uses other libraries in NetCore which do not exist on Xamarin.

By the way, if you need just a simple web server running on android like Kestrel, you can use EmdedIO. Indeed it doesn't support MVC, MVP, and MVVM, so you can not run AspNetCore app on Xamarin:
https://github.com/unosquare/embedio

Comment: by check with `https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore`, as limited checking by me for now, all related packages are marked with `.NETStandard 2.0`, so what exactly break the ASP.NET CORE using on Xamarin?